# How to change path when running java -jar from command line?

Tags: java, cmd, jar

The current path is:

Directory

- A.jar
- jre

  - bin

    - java.exe

I figured I could do something like this from the command line:

```
cd Directory/jre/bin
java -jar ../../A.jar
```

However, when I click the tab, A.jar does not appear and cannot be found.

How to do it via path move rather than specifying a path directly?

Comment: I'm sorry, what tab are you talking about?

Comment: Why don't you just put the Java directory on the PATH?

Comment: Why change directories? ```Directory\jre\bin\java.exe -jar A.jar```